# YiiStrap icons are invisible

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, icons

I downloaded fresh yiinitializr archive (from [here](http://yiinitializr.2amigos.us/)) unpacked it. After I configured db etc. I wanted to print a icon, just like it's mentioned at the yiistrap site:

```
<?php echo TbHtml::icon(TbHtml::ICON_GLASS); ?>
```

And it's invisible. There is a proper HTML code:

```
<i class="icon-glass"></i>
```

The `bootstrap.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.css` are also attached. Why it's still invisible?

Comment: How did you config?? Did you follow this page: http://www.getyiistrap.com/site/started???

Comment: Yes, I did. Maybe the yinitializr is still not ready to use it in production, despite the fact it's is pretty promising.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the icon image files. Bootstrap uses the glyphicons from http://glyphicons.com/ you need to include the icons image files.

Comment: As the yiistrap is the yii wrapper around the twitter-bootstrap, I don't think there is a need to explicitly include icons. In previous version there was no need and it would be step backward. Also yiistrap docs says that what I wrote with the `TbHtml` is enough.